# OpenPyXL - How to query cell borders?

Tags: python, openpyxl

New to both python and openpyxl.

Writing a py script to glom through a ton of Excel workbooks/sheets, and need to find certain cells identified by their border formatting.

I see several examples online of how to set cell borders, but I need to read them.

**Specifically, I wish to identify table boundaries, when the data within the table is inconsistent, but the table borders are always present. So, I need to find identify the cells with:**

```
* top / left borders
* top / right borders
* bottom / left borders
* bottom / right borders
```

(thin borders). There is only one such table per worksheet.

Could some kind maven point me to a code sample? I would provide my code thus far, but honestly I have no idea how to begin. My code for looping through each worksheet is:

```
for row in range(1, ws.max_row, 1):
    for col in range(1, sheet.max_column+1):
        tmp = NumToAlpha(col)
        ref = str(tmp) + str(row)
        hasTopBorder = ws[ref].?????? <=== how do I get a boolean here?
        hasLeftBorder = ws[ref].?????? <=== how do I get a boolean here?
        hasRightBorder = ws[ref].?????? <=== how do I get a boolean here?
        hasBottomBorder = ws[ref].?????? <=== how do I get a boolean here?
        if hasTopBorder==True and hasLeftBorder==True and hasRightBorder==False and hasBottomBorder==False: 
            tableTopLeftCell = tmp + str(row)
        elif hasTopBorder==True and hasLeftBorder==False and hasRightBorder==True and hasBottomBorder==False: 
            tableTopRightCell = tmp + str(row)
        elif hasTopBorder==False and hasLeftBorder==True and hasRightBorder==False and hasBottomBorder==True: 
            tableBottomLeftCell = tmp + str(row)
        elif hasTopBorder==False and hasLeftBorder==False and hasRightBorder==True and hasBottomBorder==True: 
            tableBottomRightCell = tmp + str(row)
        if tableTopLeftCell != "" and tableTopRightCell != "" and tableBottomLeftCell != "" and tableBottomRightCell != "": break
    if tableTopLeftCell != "" and tableTopRightCell != "" and tableBottomLeftCell != "" and tableBottomRightCell != "": break
```

*Comments/suggestions for streamlining this novice code welcome and gratefully received.*

## Update:

By querying a cell like this:

```
tst = sheet['Q17'].border
```

I see that I get this type of result - but how do I use it? Or convert it into the desired boolean?

[image: Python openpyxl cell borders]

Comment: It's not quite clear what kind of a boolean you want. You might want to look at one approach to adding borders to a group of cells to get an idea on what to test for: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#styling-merged-cells

Comment: It's a bit off-topic, but can you tell me what IDE are you using?

Comment: @HaR VS Code (the freeware version of Visual Studio and well on its way to becoming the hotest IDE). I am NO FAN of MicroSoft (thank God they fired Ballmer! - ten years too late) but love VS Code. *I dig Notepad++ a bit better, but alas she no do good Python.* PyScripter also earns high marks. Very high marks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way.

I used `is not none` because the borders could be `thin`, `double`, etc.

```
for row in range(1, ws.max_row, 1):
    for col in range(1, ws.max_column+1):
        tmp = NumToAlpha(col)
        cellRef = str(tmp) + str(row)
        cellBorders = getCellBorders(ws, cellRef)
        if ('T' in cellBorders) or  ('L' in cellBorders) or  ('R' in cellBorders) or  ('B' in cellBorders):
            if 'myTableTopLeftCell' not in refs:
                if ('T' in cellBorders) and ('L' in cellBorders):
                    refs['myTableTopLeftCell'] = (cell.row, cell.col_idx)
                    nowInmyTable = True
            if (nowInmyTable == True) and ('L' not in cellBorders):
                if 'myTableBottomLeftCell' not in refs:
                    refs['myTableBottomLeftCell'] = (cell.row-1, cell.col_idx)

def getCellBorders(ws, cellRef):
    tmp = ws[cellRef].border
    brdrs = ''

    if tmp.top.style is not None: brdrs += 'T'
    if tmp.left.style is not None: brdrs += 'L'
    if tmp.right.style is not None: brdrs += 'R'
    if tmp.bottom.style is not None: brdrs += 'B'
    return brdrs
```

Answer (score 1):

To identify whether the "Q17" has a border:

```
from openpyxl.styles.borders import Border, Side

if sheet['Q17'].border.left.style == "thin":
    print("Left side of Cell Q17 have left thin border")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around using border object by converting into JSON and getting the value of the border style

```
t = sheet.cell(1,1).border
        f = json.dumps(t,default=lambda x: x.__dict__)
        r = json.loads(f)
        s = r['left']['style']
        print(s) # which prints the value for left border style 
        if s == 'thin':
            #do specific action
```