# Python - find cell reference within merged_cells collection in openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

I wish to identify if a cell in a worksheet is found within the merged_cells collection returned by openpyxl.

The merged_cells range looks like this (VSCode debugger):

[image]

I have the cell reference `J31` - which is found in this collection. How would I write a function that returns `true` if that cell is found in the `merged_cells.ranges` collection?

Answer (score 1):

```
for cell in ^^merged_range^^:
    if cell==your_special_cell:
         return True
```

^^merged_range^^ must be of type openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range

Answer (score 0):

Further to D.Banakh's answer (+1), try something like this *(building upon a previous example I wrote for someone else, since there is little context to your question)*:

```
for cell in ws.merged_cells.ranges:
    #print(cellRef +' ==> '+ str(cell.min_row) +'/'+ str(cell.max_row) +'/'+ str(cell.min_col) +'/'+ str(cell.max_col))
    if (int(cell.min_row) <= int(row) <= int(cell.max_row)) and (int(cell.min_col) <= int(col) <= int(cell.max_col)):
        print('Cell ' +cellRef+ ' is a merged cell')
```

#### Example within a context:

```
import re

cellBorders = fnGetCellBorders(ws, cellRef)
if ('T' in cellBorders) or  ('L' in cellBorders) or  ('R' in cellBorders) or  ('B' in cellBorders) or  ('M' in cellBorders):
    print('Cell has border *OR* is a merged cell and borders cannot be checked')

def getCellBorders(ws, cellRef):
    tmp = ws[cellRef].border
    brdrs = ''

    if tmp.top.style is not None: brdrs += 'T'
    if tmp.left.style is not None: brdrs += 'L'
    if tmp.right.style is not None: brdrs += 'R'
    if tmp.bottom.style is not None: brdrs += 'B'

    if (brdrs == '') and ('condTableTopLeftCell' in refs):
        if fnIsCellWithinMergedRange(ws, cellRef): brdrs = 'M'
    return brdrs

def fnIsCellWithinMergedRange(ws, cellRef):
    ans = False
    col = fnAlphaToNum(re.sub('[^A-Z]', '', cellRef))
    row = re.sub('[^0-9]', '', cellRef)
    for cell in ws.merged_cells.ranges:
        if (int(cell.min_row) <= int(row) <= int(cell.max_row)) and (int(cell.min_col) <= int(col) <= int(cell.max_col)):
            ans = True
    return ans

def fnAlphaToNum(ltr):
    ab = ["MT", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
    return ab.index(ltr)
```

References:

[OpenPyXL - How to query cell borders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51900841/openpyxl-how-to-query-cell-borders/52299064#52299064)

[How to detect merged cells in excel with openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574991/how-to-detect-merged-cells-in-excel-with-openpyxl/42823355)

https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/911/borders-on-merged-cells-are-not-preserved

Comment: This looks pretty convoluted. I'm pretty sure CellRange provides most of the information you need.

Comment: @CharlieClark - love your openpyxl, thanks for creating it. Yeah, the example's probably a bit much - I levered this answer into a previous example to avoid conceiving a new scenario. The actual answer is the same as D.Banakh's, but fleshed out a bit more: **`for cell in ws.merged_cells.ranges:`**. *(Are you aware, though, that the cell borders are not available for merged cells -- or are you saying that even that info is available in CellRange?)* BTW, I would be interested to see how you would answer this question using CellRange... I'm not entirely sure where to start, myself.

Comment: The question doesn't ask about borders, but yes I am aware of the issue about borders. In Excel when you merge a range of cells all but the top left are deleted. Cells will, however, be created if a border is applied: this is not covered by the OOXML specification. This essentially conflates UI (the border) with data (the cells can have values even if you can't see them). 2.6 will resolve this by using read-only MergedCells.

Comment: @CharlieClark Excellent news on 2.6 - thanks very much for that update, Charlie.